# How do I move parent bone, without the child bone following its location?

Tags: animation, rigging

I am having trouble animating a weapon because I want to animate the magazine of the weapon, but I also want to animate the weapon itself too, but since the magazine is a child of the weapon bone it will always follow its location and it will look weird when I try to animate both of them, so is there a fix to this? (I am trying to avoid unparenting the objects if possible)

Answer (score 2):

You don't.  The whole point of parenting is that the children move with the parent.  But, if you don't *connect* the child bone to the parent bone then you can move the child after you've moved the parent:

[image: Bone properties showing Connected state]

If you really want the child to only sometimes be a child, instead of parenting it, give it a *Child Of* constraint.  You can then set the *influence* to 0 when you want the child to be completely independent of the parent and 1 when you want it to move with the parent:

[image: Child Of constraint with Influnece highlighted]

You add a Bone constraint by selecting the bone in *Pose* mode and going to the *Bone Constraint Properties* tab of the Properties editor.